# Mapping array additionally to existing hash in Perl

Tags: perl, hash, hashmap

How can I add elements in existing hash like push in array but using mapping?

If I do:

```
%existing_hash = map { $_ => 1 } @new_elements;
```

This resets the %existing_hash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
%existing_hash = (%existing_hash, map { $_ => 1 } @new_elements);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think I'd do it the simple way:

```
$existing_hash{$_} = 1 for @new_elements;
```

But you could also use a hash slice:

```
@existing_hash{@new_elements} = (1) x @new_elements;
```

Comment: Your first solution works well too and looks simple, thanks for great idea.